# Android 9 surface not onKey for back batton (navigation) during first start of application

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, onbackpressed

My application works fine from android 4.2 to 9.0 but on Android 9.0 just for first time start SurfaceView not receive onKey event when I press back button (navigation). After restart on just after hide and show again application all works fine. This callback not working:

```
// View.OnKeyListener interface
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

I try every property I know(in constructor):

```
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
requestFocus();
setOnTouchListener(this);
setOnKeyListener(this);
```

In Activity method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
```

works all the time. May be somthing changed in Android 9.0 and I should add or set some new property? My environment Google Pixel 3. May be this is known Android 9 problem? Thanks in advance!